# Markdown external image links with Redcarpet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redcarpet

I am using the redcarpet gem to markdown user generated text and would like to show images of external links/image hosts.  So far, I have tried something like this:

```
def markdown(text)
   options = { ... }
   extension = { ... }
   text.gsub!(/(https?:\/\/[\S]*.jpg)/, '<img src="\1" width="100%">')
   renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)
   markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
   markdown.render(text).html_safe
end
```

However, I would like to `escape_html` or `filter_html`, because injecting `</div>`, `id`s, and classes can really mess up the site.  This would remove the image tag.

Is there any better way to go about rendering external images while keeping the HTML safe?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
require "redcarpet"
require "action_view"

class HTMLBlockCode < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

  def image(link, title, alt_text)
    image_tag(link, title: title, alt: alt_text, width: "100%")
  end
end

def markdown(text)
   renderer = HTMLBlockCode.new
   text.gsub!(/(https?:\/\/[\S]*.jpg)/, '![](\1)')
   markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer)
   markdown.render(text)
end

text = File.read("rc_test.md")

puts markdown(text)
```

This installs a custom image renderer on RedCarpet, which adds a `width="100%"` attribute to your image elements.  It also converts bare image links to markdown-recognized image links in the `gsub` call.  This results in an embedded image url being rendered like this:

```
<img width="100%" src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" />
```

And you don't have to change your markdown document in any way; it's automagically delicious.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work for me. The output is now all the html elements in text form, the images do not get rendered.

Comment: I updated the answer, and this is going to be much better for what you're trying to do.  Please do let me know if you have any questions.